# Error Handling when using annotations

Tags: spring-statemachine

I'm following the documentation ([State Machine Error Handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-error-handling)) to implement error handling. However, when an exception occurs it is propagated up rather than intercepted. I tried using the interceptor, the listener and the `@OnStateMachineError` without any success. Debugging the code, neither `MethodInvokingStateMachineRuntimeProcessor.java:52` or any of its callers have any specific logic to handle errors.

Replicating the issue is simple, just create a state machine (I'm using the latest snapshot) and register the bean:

```
@WithStateMachine
public class ExceptionThrowingAction {
    @OnTransition
    public void throwError(@EventHeaders Map<String, Object> headers, ExtendedState extendedState) {
        throw new RuntimeException("test error");
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or is it a genuine bug? If so, I'll raise as an issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bug. We've done a lot of changes in master to harden there user level hooks. None of those should break machine execution. Please raise an issue and we'll fix it.